# how to open a xyz.int.tr.gz file in linux

Tags: linux, radtreeview, radtreelist

I have been trying to open a large compressed file on linux and getting this error.
1)First I gunzipped the file 
gunzip georegion_v2.v6.int.tr.gz 
and this file got created -> georegion_v2.v6.int.tr

2)Now I want to open this file and perform operations on it, but I ma getting following error.

tar -zxvf xyz.int.tr 
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Can you please tell me what is needed here ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use tar to both gunzip and untar it at the same time like this:

```
tar -xzvf xyz.in.tr.gz
```

If that still doesn't work then this is not a tar.gz file or it is corrupted. The tr.gz extension is a bit unusual. It is usually tar.gz.

Your problem was that your were passing the z flag after you gunzip the file. So it looks for a gzipped tar file but is finding an ordinary tar file instead.

Comment: So, I found out that the file is not corrupted but it using radtree.

For ex, I want to find out number of elements in the file,

radtreev6/TreeToolsInt tree2list georegion.v6.int.tr |wc -l
179619

But I am not sure what is radtree or ToolsInt or tree2list .

Can you explain?

Thank you for responding :)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what radtree is, or really what your follow-up question is. If this is a tar.gz file then my answer should work. If it is just a simple gzipped file with a .tr extension then you have already decompressed it. If you have more questions about radtree or then you should probably post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous response and your question, this does not appear to be a .tar.gz file type since the file extension is .tr.gz unless you made a typo. You said you ran gunzip on xyz.int.tr.gz and now it is xyz.int.tr.

Can you please run `file xyz.int.tr` to see if that helps determine the correct file type? Most likely you will need to find out what type of file this is and the correct software in order to use this file.